# How to use recursive db call in apache ignite?

Tags: ignite

I have to fetch data in tree structure. My table is having id and parent_tag_id column. If i am passing any id then i have to fetch all the childern of given id.
How to implement to fetch data in tree structure in apache ignite?

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing this efficiently (and in general, any parent -> child relations) is to use SQL queries. There are number of approach of dealing with hierarchical data with SQL.

Comment: i checked for mysql and sql db there are some pre-defined function to implement the recursive call but ignite doesn't support those functions. Can you please tell me how to implement it using sql queries.